# Scala/Spark randomSplit

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to make a model using training and testing data. 
I want to control in case of arguments: 
1. If I get one argument (one file path) by console, I want to split the data.
2. If I get two arguments (two file paths), one is the training and the other one the test data.
3. Other case, take one by default.

The problem is to define the variable before the condition. I don't know how it works the Some/Option/None sentence and I get and error some steps after this:

```
var dataTraining: Option[RDD[String]]=None
var dataTesting: Option[RDD[String]]=None

if(args.length==1){
      val data=sc.textFile(args(0))
      val splitData=data.randomSplit(Array(0.8,0.2),seed=11L)
      (dataTraining,DataTesting)=(Some(splitData(0)),Some(splitData(1)))
}
else if(args.length==2){
      dataTraining=Some(sc.textFile(args(0))
      dataTesting=Some(sc.textFile(args(1))
}
else{
      dataTraining=Some(sc.textFile("/ruta")
      dataTesting=Some(sc.textFile("/ruta2")
}
```

I don't get any error here, but when I want to try to do: .map(_.split(',')), intellij can't reconice split function. Maybe the type of dataTraining/dataTesting is not the correct one.

¿What is my mistake?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

How about simple pattern matching:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  val (dataTraining, dataTesting) = args match {
    case Array(p) => 
       val splits = sc.textFile(p).randomSplit(Array(0.8,0.2),seed=11L)
       (splits(0), splits(1))

   case Array(p1, p2) => (sc.textFile(p1), sc.textFile(p2))

   case _ => (sc.textFile("/ruta"), sc.textFile("/ruta"))
  }
}
```

Regarding the issue you most likely apply `map` only to an `Option` not a `RDD`. You need something like this:

```
val optionRdd: Option[RDD[String]] = ???

optionRdd.map(_.map(_.split(",")))
```

where the outer `map` maps over the `Option` and the inner one over the `RDD`.